# Почему нельзя использовать ToString() на Коллекциях?

Tags: c#, коллекции

При вызове на коллекции `List` метода `ToString()` выводится следующее:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

я нашёл решение данной проблемы:

```
string combindedString = string.Join( ",", myList );
```

Но, я до сих пор не могу понять, почему же мы не можем на коллекции использовать метод `ToString()` для получения строки из коллекции

Comment: `ToArray` не нужен. _почему же мы не можем на коллекции использовать метод ToString() для получения строки из коллекции_ - использовать можешь, просто данный метод у коллекций не переопределен и используется базовый метод из Object

Comment: @Grundy , метол 'Join' вторым параметром требует массив строк 'string[]' для этого и вызывается 'ToArray()'

Comment: У данного метода несколько перегрузок: [Метод String.Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: хотя судя по тому, что у тебя `List<string>`, подойдет и вот эта: [Метод String.Join (String, IEnumerable<String>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Да, действительно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что коллекция не знает, в каком виде вы хотите получить её. Может быть, вы хотите разделить запятыми. Может быть, вы хотите перед каждой запятой пробел. Может, вы хотите перед последним элементом не запятую, а союз «и». Может быть, элементы коллекции сами могут содержать запятые, и вы хотите разделить из точками с запятой или там вывести по одному на строчку, или заключить в кавычки. Или ещё как-то.

Реализовывать все эти возможности при помощи параметризации было бы глупо: вариантов *слишком* много. Там более, что простые случаи наподобие разделения запятыми легко кодируются вручную.

Comment: можно было бы передавать какой-нибудь форматтер в ToString :)

Comment: @Grundy: Параметризация слишком сложная выходит. Например, я хочу передавать отступ слева для каждой строки, как? Форматтер должен быть очень умный, если уж его писать, то и ToString на надо, просто Formatter.Format и всё.

Comment: Но для чисел же сделали

Comment: @Grundy: Там набор вариантов обозримее всё же. Но всё равно очень большой.

Comment: Ну как бы принимали б IFormatProvider и все, как реализовали так и вывелось и по дефолту какой-нибудь сделали бы и все

Comment: @Grundy: «как реализовали так и вывелось» — это как бы не очень хороший подход, см. весь язык Javascript :)

Comment: JavaScript - шикарен :-D

Comment: @Grundy: [Wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)?

Comment: Это неосиляторы, там все на самом деле логично было

Comment: @Grundy: Как хорошо, что в C# не пошли этим _простым логичным путём_!

Answer (score 2):

Это стандартное поведение виртуального метода `ToString` класса `Object`. У класса `List` он не переопределен. Чтобы сделать это просто наследуйтесь от класса `List`:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Join(",", this);
        }
    }
```

Далее вместо экземпляров класса `List` создавайте экземпляры класса `MyList` и работайте с ними так же как и раньше. При этом `ToString` этого класса будет делать то, что вам нужно)

Еще удобно использовать так называемые методы расширения:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static string ToString(this IList list, string separator)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, list.GetEnumerator());
    }
}
```

Можете то же самое сделать в целом для IEnumerable.
Использование: `myList.ToString(",")`

Comment: при вызове `myList.ToString(",")` метод расширения никогда не вызовется, потому что всегда есть метод ToString. Кроме того, в примере с расширением куча ошибок(нет класса List, не используется separator, не используется list, не возвращается результат), его стоит либо исправить, либо убрать

Comment: @Grundy, Почему метод расширения никогда не вызовется? У него есть 1 параметр, у стандартного 0 параметров, не? Ошибок не нашел.

Comment: _Ошибок не нашел_ - а ты пробовал этот в студию вставить? **нет класса List, не используется separator, не используется list, не возвращается результат**. Да, действительно запустится с одним парамтером

Comment: @Grundy, упс, простите, не докопировал) Исправил. Спасибо.

Comment: Теперь у тебя два одинаковых примера - это раз. предварительный Select не нужен, можно было сразу `this` передавать `return string.Join(",", this);`

Comment: @Grundy, согласен)